# Why listbox selection changed not working properly in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
private void PersonalInfoList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                System.Collections.IList list = e.AddedItems;
                if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Category> categs = list.Cast<Category>();
                    Category em = categs.ElementAt<Category>(0);
                    int id = em.id;
                    int categoryid = em.categoryid;
                    string subcategoryname = em.subcategname;

                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/SubCategories.xaml?id=" + id + "&categoryid=" + categoryid + "&subcategoryname=" + subcategoryname), UriKind.Relative));
                }
            }
```

if 2 items are there  in list if click on first item then able to navigate to subcategories page.but again click on same first item not able to navigate.if click on 2 item after click on first item then able to navigate to subcategories page.....

Comment: apply Tap event instead on selection changed event. That is less ambigous and more effective. As in case you need to reload the list or reset the selected index value everytime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `PersonalInfoList.SelectedIndex` to `-1` before or after your call to `NavigationService.Navigate` to reset the selected item.

If you are using a LongListSelector, set the `SelectedItem` to `null`

Answer (score 2):

As Claus mentions in his answer, You need to set the `PersonalInfoList.SelectedIndex` to `-1`. However, if you are just rendering a list which is used for navigation, I created a `NavigationList` for this purpose:

[A Fast Loading Windows Phone 7 NavigationList Control](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/04/a-fast-loading-windows-phone-7-navigationlist-control/)

This has the advantage of loading approximately twice as fast as a `ListBox`, also you do not have the same problem of having to 'reset' the selected-index.